# typeahead remote only returning one item

Tags: typeahead.js

I cannot make typeahead work for me.

My html code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>


<div id="remote">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Oscar winners for Best Picture">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: '/service-autocomplete.php'
            }
        });



        $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            name: 'best-pictures',
            display: 'value',
            source: bestPictures
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my service (service-autocomplete.php) contains this:

```
<?php




$data = [
    [
        "value" => "amelie",
    ],
    [
        "value" => "anastasia",
    ],
    [
        "value" => "paul",
    ],
    [
        "value" => "pierre",
    ],
];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now whatever I type in the input (1 letter, or multiple letters), only the first suggestion appear (amelie).

I expected typeahead to display all the results: amelie, anastasia, pierre, paul.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin called jquery.typeahead:
http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/

It does all I need, and more, plus it works right off the bat.
So, I switched to jquery.typeahead.